# How to fix overlapping mesh vertices(improper vertex placements after modifiers apply)?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices

[image]

Hi guys I am working on a model when I applied the solidify and the subdiv modifier together, I dunno how but I got this weird mesh that I am trying to correct, although I worked with similar issue before, I am not able to understand a workaround for this particular problem.[image]

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Before applying the modifiers, always make sure that you keep the non-destructive version (a version of your object with modifiers non-applied)

Comment: Agree with @moonboots. Can't really help now that the modifiers are applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before applying the modifiers, always make sure that you keep the non-destructive version (a version of your object with modifiers non-applied). From you version you could select all the front faces with a <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, and use the *Threshold* value to extend the selection (unselect the faces that are behind though):

[image]

Remove these faces, also remove these edges:

[image]

Dissolve these edges at the bottom:

[image]

Fill these faces with multiple <kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]

Create the 2 edge loops if necessary:

[image]

Comment: hey @moonbots, how do you repeat a action multiple times, like constantly pressing F to fill, I am trying it but  unable to do so

Comment: You need to select one edge, then press F and F again

Comment: I think you need the built-in F2 addon enabled for that. Most people have that enabled and forgot they enabled it ! :^)

Comment: Not in the latest versions but yes, if he has a previous version, he needs to enable the F2 addon

Comment: Ah ok. I enabled it in 2.8 and forgot about it! :^)